# Debug Visualizer for xCode

Tags: xcode, debugging, debuggervisualizer

According to this book [XCode by James Bucanek](http://books.google.com/books?id=2-rM9yP7_hUC&pg=PA374&lpg=PA374&dq=xcode%20step%20out%20of%20machine%20code&source=bl&ots=_zVTFIvvnW&sig=tZCHnMG9WqHtN-z7LFFWpil-z0s&hl=en&ei=zrbZTpjMGYrQiAKD6YWDCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=debug%20visualizer&f=false) the xCode comes with a Debug Visualizer. But the author never mentions how to open it, a surprise. Does anybody know how to open Debug Visualizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A book *Beginning Xcode* by *James Bucanek* was published in 2006 for xCode 2. In modern versions of xCode there's no Debug Visualizer.

I suggest you to find more up-to-date book about xCode.